# MySQL error on trying to open a MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I'm getting the following error when I try to open up a connection with MySQL running on my MACBOOK:

Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Users/Eugene/Sites/website/includes/database.php on line 15 Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /Users/Eugene/Sites/website/includes/database.php on line 15 Notice: Undefined variable: connection in /Users/Evgeny/Sites/website/includes/database.php on line 16 Database connection failed: No such file or directory

My constants are:

```
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
defined('DB_USER') ? null : define("DB_USER", "eugene");
defined('DB_PASS') ? null : define("DB_PASS", "password"); // no comments please :)
defined('DB_NAME') ? null : define("DB_NAME", "maindb");
```

The way I try to connect is:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
if(!$connection) // if no connection - die
{
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
else // if there is a connection, then go and select a database
{
    $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection);
    if(!$db_select) // if no database selected - die
    {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Confirm you can connect via the command line:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

First problem is that mysqld is not using the same socket path as the client. Try accessing via 127.0.0.1 then run 'show variables' to find it where it has put the socket - update your PHP config appropriately.

> if(!$connection)

But you put the connection in '$this->connection' not '$connection'

Comment: thanks for your reply, it was a typo on my side while i was writing the question.

Comment: BTW, this _seems_ to be solvable (if you have enought access) by fixing the `[mysql_client]` portion of `my.cnf` (most often found in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`). Somewhere along the line the default socket was changed from `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` to `/var/mysql/mysqld.sock` and all hell broke loose. Or you can remove the socket reference from that `[mysql_client]` portion altogether to force tcp (which is what the 127.0.0.1 does).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an instance variable via `$this` but testing a local variable. Assuming no other changes, your code should look like:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
if (!$connection) // if no connection - die
{
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Give that a try!

Comment: oh yeah sorry i made a typo writing this question, still not working though :(

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing class variables and local variables. `$this->connection` is not the same as `$connection`.

Answer (score 0):

If u'are calling $connection from a class just put if(!$this->connection){.....}
or if not just put this line if (!$connection){.....}